# wordpress. character limit on category title using substr

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code. Now i want to add "..." at the end of every category titles  with more than 10 characters.'

sample: coconut is the b...

how to do that?

```
<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . substr($category->cat_name, 0, 10) . ' </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the string length first to see that the string is larger than 10 characters:

```
<?php
    $current_cat    =   get_query_var('cat');
    $categories     =   get_categories('orderby=id&order=desc&number=16');
    foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
            <div class="latest">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array( 160,100 ), array( 'class' => 'primary' )); ?>
                <img src="domain.com/images/<?php echo $category->category_nicename; ?>.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="latest-details"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>"><?php echo substr($category->cat_name, 0, 10); echo (strlen($category->cat_name) > 10)? "...":""; ?></a>
 <?php } ?>
```

Here is the manual for `strlen()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Answer (score 2):

```
if (substr($category->cat_name,0,10) != $category->cat_name)
{
  $category->cat_name = substr($category->cat_name,0,10);
  $category->cat_name .= '...';
}
```

Will do this. Set your output without substr() after this if statement, you can keep $category->cat_name as object

Comment: sorry. i don't really get it.
heres my entire code for this. 
<?php
        $current_cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
$categories = get_categories('orderby=id&order=desc&number=16');

foreach($categories as $category) {
echo '<div class="latest">'; ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array( 160,100 ), array( 'class' => 'primary' )); ?>
<?php echo '<img src="http://domain.com/images/' . $category->category_nicename . '.jpg" /></div><div class="latest-details"><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . substr($category->cat_name, 0, 10) . ' </a>'; } ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function stringLimit($text,$limit){
       $length = strlen($text);
       if($length>$limit){ 
           $finalText= substr($text,0,$limit)."...";} 
           else {$finalText=$text;}
    return $finalText;
    } 
$text = stringLimit($text,10);
```

Hope this will help you.